# VS 2015 Team Explorer Code Review Request Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, team-explorer

I would like some guidance if possible. We have recently moved to VSTS in the Cloud and since that migration, we are having an issue requesting code reviews. As an example, if I look at change history, right click and choose "Request Review", the action generates a New Code Review in the Team Explorer window, but there is an error message:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error
>   generating the XML document. ---> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Where are the details (eg stack trace) for this error? I've tried to use the VS 2015 activity log (/log option), but that doesn't appear to give me any guidance and I've use the find in files selection in VS 2015 to search all of my specific AppData folders for pieces of the error message with no results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try attaching a second instance of Visual Studio as a debugger to the other while turning on "Break on all Exceptions" and disabling "Just my Code".

Comment: Thanks much, jessehouwing! That caught the error(s) - actually a series of five exceptions, with a SOAP casting error which must be some issue with datacontracts. During my earlier troubleshooting, I saw errors in the Activity.log stating that Team Explorer's extension was duplicated while loading. All-in-all, it gets me looking a bit further into the issue, and I thank you very very much!

Comment: Sounds like you may have an extension installed that ships with tfs client object model assemblies.

Comment: Did this issue only occurs on your VS or also with your co-worker 's machine?

Comment: This has been remedied by Microsoft on the data behind cloud service. It appears that the migration from on-prem to cloud introduced a mis-mapping of the Reviewed-by field. So, the error occurred with anyone that had previously requested a code review or finished a code review, which was nearly everyone. The data has been purged and remapped, so we have returned to normal ops.